# Xposed Framework with KitKat ART?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, boot-loop, dalvik, art, xposed-framework

I have an SGS-I8190 with CM11 from http://maclaw.pl/

I explored the Xposed Framework, but it is not compatible with ART. It switches back to the old buggy and lame Dalvik. XDA says, that ART provides a Bootloop in addition to xposes.

Is a workaround to use both, or do I have to live with either one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of this moment, it is a known fact (not necessarily an issue) that the [Xposed framework](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1574401) DOES NOT WORK with ART.

So, you either:

- Stay with Dalvik runtime, and get the advantage of using Xposed; OR
- Uninstall Xposed framework, and get the advantage of using ART

> **After installing Xposed, the runtime gets reset from ART to Dalvik. Can you stop it please?**
>
> You can be glad that I implemented this, otherwise you would be in a
>   bootloop know. **Xposed isn't compatible with ART (yet).** It's a
>   completely different architecture with pretty much no documentation.
>   Rewriting Xposed for the ART runtime requires understanding the
>   concept, the code structure and many details to know how it works. I
>   have already spent dozens of hours on that and some things are
>   working. But still it's a long way ahead. Don't expect even a test
>   version in the near future. So please don't ask when it will be
>   available - you will surely know when it is ready. I have nothing else
>   to say about that.